# Custom fonts not working with iMessage Extension in iOS 10

Tags: swift3, ios10, ios-extensions, imessage-extension

I am developing iMessage Extension, in which i need custom font same i used in its container application. In iOS App custom fonts working fine. But in iMessage Extension it accessible in Interface builder but when display in output there is no custom font effect. It displays with system font.

**Interface Builder UI Design**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

I also set `Fonts provided by application` in `info.plist` file of iMessage Extension, but not working.

Is it possible to access custom font in iMessage Extension ? or there is any other way to use it ?

If any one have idea then please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Make sure you have added All TTF file in your project resource. And Also select **Target Membership** for all Target in which you want to use this font. Check below image for that.

[image]